# How to extract specific values from a HTML table and copy them horizontally to a file using PowerShell?

Tags: html, regex, powershell

**Code**

```
select-string -Path "input.txt" -Pattern '<td>[A-Z][a-z]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > 'outcome.txt'
```

and

```
select-string -Path "input.txt" -Pattern '\d+K' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > 'outcome2.txt'
```

**Input**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Population</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amsterdam</td>
    <td>900K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rotterdam</td>
    <td>700K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The Hague</td>
    <td>500K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Utrecht</td>
    <td>300K</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

**Current outcome**

*outcome.txt*

```
<td>Amsterdam
<td>Rotterdam
<td>The
<td>Utrecht
```

*outcome2.txt*

```
900K
700K
500K
300K
```

**Expected outcome**

```
Amsterdam 900K
Rotterdam 700K
The Hague 500K
Utrecht 300K
```

**Problems**

*Horizontal display*

First, the outcome of outcome.txt and outcome2.txt could be merged manually, but this is an example and the actual file contains thousands of lines and more than 100 columns.

*Specific extraction*

Second, the actual regex would be far more extensive, the lines could contain more than 500 characters and a specific get should be done, e.g. in case of `<td>Utrecht</td>` the expected outcome is `Utrecht` rather than `<td>Utrecht`

**Update**

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("input.txt")) {
#  if ($line -match '<td>(.*)</td>\n<td>(\d+)</td>') {
  if ($line -match '<td>(.*)(</td>)') {  
     $matches[1] + $matches[2]
  }  
}
```

results in:

```
Amsterdam</td>
900K</td>
Rotterdam</td>
700K</td>
The Hague</td>
500K</td>
Utrecht</td>
300K</td>
```

The current problem is that the `out-commented \n` will not match the second line, while the test indicates that it is possible to extract a second element using a second parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have another approach there is already people who have created cmdlets to do the hard work for you by converting the table to an object. From the [PowerShell Code Repository](http://poshcode.org/4850) with credit going to Joel Bennett.

```
function ConvertFrom-Html {
   #.Synopsis
   #   Convert a table from an HTML document to a PSObject
   #.Example
   #   Get-ChildItem | Where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ConvertTo-Html | ConvertFrom-Html -TypeName Deserialized.System.IO.FileInfo
   #   Demonstrates round-triping files through HTML
   param(
      # The HTML content
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [string]$html,

      # A TypeName to inject to PSTypeNames 
      [string]$TypeName
   )
   begin { $content = "$html" }
   process { $content += "$html" }
   end {
      [xml]$table = $content -replace '(?s).*<table[^>]*>(.*)</table>.*','<table>$1</table>'

      $header = $table.table.tr[0]  
      $data = $table.table.tr[1..1e3]

      foreach($row in $data){ 
         $item = @{}

         $h = "th"
         if(!$header.th) {
            $h = "td"
         }
         for($i=0; $i -lt $header.($h).Count; $i++){
            if($header.($h)[$i] -is [string]) {
               $item.($header.($h)[$i]) = $row.td[$i]
            } else {
               $item.($header.($h)[$i].InnerText) = $row.td[$i]
            }
         }
         Write-Verbose ($item | Out-String)
         $object = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $item 
         if($TypeName) {
            $Object.PSTypeNames.Insert(0,$TypeName)
         }
         Write-Output $Object
      }
   }
}
```

Using your table data as input the above outputs the following:

```
Get-Content "input.txt" | ConvertFrom-Html

City      Population
----      ----------
Amsterdam 900K      
Rotterdam 700K      
The Hague 500K      
Utrecht   300K
```

That should be easier to work with depending on where you are going.... like say Export-CSV or some such thing. With the data as an object you could go almost anywhere.